# Redirecting .html file to another one in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect from one html file to another using the following rules (that also do other rewrites I need):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^/TalkLounge/quote-43735\.html$  /TalkLounge/4/best-way$ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The last redirect works but the previous ones add `?qa-rewrite=quote-43735` which I don't want to be added. Is there any way to avoid that?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried excluding qua-rewrite before the second to last rule?

Comment: Yes but i need that rule

Comment: I added an answer to elaborate what I mean by exclude it from the rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can reorder or add a comment mark (#):

```
RewriteRule ^/TalkLounge/quote-43735\.html$  /TalkLounge/4/best-way$ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Or:

```
# RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^/TalkLounge/quote-43735\.html$  /TalkLounge/4/best-way$ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: No it doesn't work - same result or even breaks my other links (to .css files, for example)

Comment: If the last line just use to redirect one page, why you not using a javascript redirect or a refresh meta tag in that file? (quote-43735.html)

Comment: i can't i don't have that file on the server and i want to do it through htaccess for seo

Answer (score 0):

It appears the second to last rule is capturing the request for quote-43735.html and inserting it as the value to query key qa-rewrite. If so, then add a RewriteCond to exclude it.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !quote-43735\.html$
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```